# Separar valores de uma string e executar uma função com a mesma

Tags: php

Olá,

Tenho uma string que o valor é zero (`$contador = 0;`), outra que o valor é três (`$vezes = 3;`) e outra que é `$numeros = "13|123456789\n14|123456780\n"`.

Quero que o PHP faça uma função (exemplo `echo();`) até a string `$contador` chegue no três, e fazer essa função com os 2 valores na string `$numeros`, por exeplo:

```
$ddd = 13; //Pega o valor 13 da string $numeros
$numero = 123456789; //Pega o valor 123456789 da string $numeros
echo "Meu DDD é $ddd e meu celular é $numero!";
//Resposta (vai repetir a função echo acima 3 vezes graças ao valor da string $vezes):
// Meu DDD é 13 e meu celular é 123456789!
// Meu DDD é 13 e meu celular é 123456789!
// Meu DDD é 13 e meu celular é 123456789!
```

Mesma coisa com o segundo valor da string `$numeros`. E quando o valor da string `$contador` chegar a três, o script para.

Não consegui pensar em nada que fizesse isso, grato à todos des de já!

Comment: `13|123456789\n14|123456780\n` é assim que você têm os dados? Não entendi a parte onde o loop entre nisso. São sempre 2 números de telefone?

Comment: @PapaCharlie Os dados são enviados de um formulário em POST, desse formato ``DD|NUMERO``, quero uma função que a cada linha que o usuário adicionar (``\n``) o script faz a função que eu citei.

Comment: Você precisa formatar `13|123456789\n14|123456780\n` em **13(\*)123456789; 14(\*)123456780**, isso?

Comment: Exatamente, mas com tanto que a formatação não afete o resultado com a função, por exemplo ``echo "Meu DDD é 13.. e meu celular é 123456789"``

Comment: Como se fosse uma array

Comment: Acabei de ler aqui no php.net, não entendi muito, por isso achei melhor abrir uma questão aqui no stackoverflow

Comment: Dei uma resposta com base no que entendi da sua questão, se estiver incorreto eu edito. Veja se resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php):

```
$numeros = "13|123456789\n14|123456780\n";

$contador = 0;
$vezes = 3;

while ($contador < $vezes) {
    $linhas = explode("\n", $numeros);

    foreach($linhas as $linha){
        list($ddd, $numero) = array_pad(explode('|', $linha, 2), 2, null);

        if (isset($ddd, $numero)){
            echo "Meu DDD é $ddd e meu celular é $numero!\n";
        }
        $contador++;
    }

}

// Meu DDD é 13 e meu celular é 123456789!
// Meu DDD é 14 e meu celular é 123456780!
```

[Ver `demonstração`](https://ideone.com/5Xxrk4)

Comment: Deu um erro na demonstração e aqui. `Undefined offset: 1 on line number 11`

Comment: @STRILEXLIVE Já arrumei o erro, veja se é isso que você quer. Usei a variável `contador` dentro do `foreach` para não repetir os mesmos resultados a cada iteração do `while`, você pode colocar a variável `contador` fora do `foreach` se quiser.

Answer (score 2):

O que você quer é fazer um loop, existem vários e vários modos de fazer isso e vários tópicos sobre isso aqui.

Se a string se manter: `(DDD)|(NUMERO)\n`, a cada `\n` você terá um `(DDD)|(NUMERO)`, logo divida o `|` e terá o `(DDD)` e o `(NUMERO)` de cada conjunto.

Primeiro quebre a string usando `explode`:

```
$numeros = "13|123456789\n14|123456780\n";
$numeros = explode("\n", $numeros);
```

Agora você terá um array para cada `(DDD)|(NUMERO)`.

Então use pode usar o `for`:

```
for($contador = 0; $contador < 3; $contador++){

    if(isset($numeros[$contador]) && !empty($numeros[$contador])){

     // Use outro explode para dividir entre DDD e NUMERO
     list($ddd, $numero) = explode("|", $numeros[$contador]);
     echo "Meu DDD é $ddd e meu celular é $numero!";
    }

}
```

Você também pode usar o `foreach`, para listar TODOS:

> Você também pode limitar usando `if($index === 3){break;}` por exemplo!

```
foreach($numeros as $index => $numero){

    if(!empty($numero)){
         list($ddd, $numero) = explode("|", $numero);
         echo "Meu DDD é $ddd e meu celular é $numero!";
    }

}
```

Você pode [testar ambos clicando aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a1f8603b425d973c4628a1a298946445b85620ff)

Comment: Mas eu quero receber os valores das strings ``$ddd`` e ``$numero`` da string ``$numeros``

Comment: Como se fosse uma array, entende?

Comment: Eu editei, veja se é isso. :s

Comment: Tá quase certo, você ta pensando que o ``$contador`` está definindo o tanto de vez que vai fazer a função ``echo``, o ``$contador`` é pra repetir o tanto de vez que a função vai ocorrer.

Answer (score 1):

Usando [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) para obter os números apenas. Você terá um array como abaixo.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 123456789
            [2] => 14
            [3] => 123456780
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 123456789
            [2] => 14
            [3] => 123456780
        )

)
```

---

Usando os índices do array, você pode fazer facilmente juntar o DDD e o número do telefone.

```
preg_match_all( '/(\d+)/' , '13|123456789\n14|123456780\n', $fone );

echo $fone[0][0] . '**' . $fone[0][1]; // 13**123456789
echo $fone[0][2] . '**' . $fone[0][3]; // 14**123456789
```